# Why did it take Thanos 3 years to get to the Space Stone?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

Here is the storyline:

*Avengers: Age of Ultron*         Thanos decides to do it by himself.
*Captain America: Civil War*    Scott Lang is put under house arrest for **3** years.
*Ant-man and the Wasp*            Scott's three years are almost over while the Infinity War is passing.

What was Thanos doing almost 3 years? Maybe it was hard to get the Power Stone? Or maybe he couldn't find the Space Stone?

Comment: You might find it easier to use the Official MCU Timeline ... published recently. https://screenrant.com/mcu-timeline-official/

Comment: This shows that it was 2015 that Thanos declares he'll do it himself, and 2017 when Infinity War takes place.  So infact "only" around 2 years has elapsed

Comment: @iandotkelly Still a long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because now he knows the location of all of them and it's time to "Catch Em All ".

From [slashfilm](https://www.slashfilm.com/why-thanos-waited/):

> It turns out there’s a good reason for why Thanos waited so long, and Infinity War co-writer Stephen McFeely explains it below.
>
> [LRM Online](https://lrmonline.com/news/avengers-infinity-war-directors-on-why-thanos-didnt-strike-sooner/) pulled a quote from Stephen McFeely, who co-wrote the script with Christopher Markus, off of the Avengers: Infinity War commentary. (The film just hit Digital HD and comes to Blu-ray later this month.) Here’s what McFeely said about Thanos’s timetable:
>
> > “The catalyst for the whole movie was when **Thanos figured out where the Soul Stone was** because he captured Nebula on his ship [after she went after him at the end of Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2] and rooted around in her brain and found out that Gamora knew where the Soul Stone was…
> >
> > Normally you want, you know, your inciting incident, the catalyst for this to maybe be on screen and maybe be first. But given how we wanted to approach the story we buried it to basically the midpoint. And, you know, again, it keeps you off balance, but it’s definitely there.”